# Problema de Herencia en Python que no entiendo

Tags: python-3.x, herencia

De manera casual he encontrado este código de Python y el problema es que no entiendo, me resulta inaccesible. Si alguien me puede explicar porqué el código da el resultado que obtengo se lo agradeceré.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
        self.calc(10)
        print('i from A is', self.i)

    def calc(self, i):
        self.i = 2 * i


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def calc(self, i):
            self.i = 3 * i
    
b = B()
```

El resultado que devuelve es la impresión de la cadena:

```
i from A is 30
```

Pero cómo toma i el valor 30? Si en ningún momento se llama al método de B calc()

Comment: "*...en ningún momento se llama al método de B...*". Si se llama. La instancia se está creando desde la clase `B`, que a su vez hereda de `A`. Como `B` y `A` tienen el mismo método `calc()`, entonces el de la hija `B` sobreescribe al de su padre `A`. Por eso cuando en `A` se ejecuta `self.calc(10)`, se usa el método de `B`, ya que el suyo ha sido sobreescrito. Puedes pegar el código [ACÁ](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) y verificar paso a paso la ejecución.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si que lo has llamado, ya que creas una instancia de B. La pila de llamadas va así:

```
b = B()  
# invoca a 
B.__init__(b)
#que tiene esta línea super().__init__() que invoca a 
A.__init__(b)
# que tiene esta línea: self.calc(10), que invoca a 
B.calc(b, 10)
```

Esto puede parecer incorrecto de entrada, pero recuerda que la variable `self` es una instancia de la clase `B`, no de la clase `A`, por lo que los métodos a los que se llama son, en primer lugar, los métodos de la clase `B`, y solo si esta no los ha definido se buscarán en la clase `A`, que es la clase padre, y luego en `object`, que es la clase base de todos los objetos.

A esto se le llama [*polimorfismo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

También recuerda que en Python los métodos son totalmente dinámicos, a diferencia de otros lenguajes, los objetos no tienen que derivar de la misma clase para portarse de manera polimórfica. Ya que todo se resuelve en tiempo de ejecución (al interpretar el script), incluso puedes llamar a métodos con el mismo nombre declarados en clases totalmente independientes, y siempre se llamará al método más *cercano* en la jerarquía de clases de cada instancia.

Mira este otro ejemplo, que espero te ayude con esto último que menciono:

```
class Padre:
    def saludar(self):
        if self.__class__ == Padre:
            print("padre saludando")
        else:
            print("padre saludando porque " + self.__class__.__name__ + " no saluda")

class Hijo(Padre):
    def saludar(self):
        print("hijo saludando")
        
class MalHijo(Padre):
    def noSaludar():
        print("yo no saludo!")

class Otra:
    def saludar(self):
        print("otra saludando")
        
lista = list()
lista.append(Padre())
lista.append(Hijo())
lista.append(MalHijo())
lista.append(Otra())

for x in lista:
    x.saludar()
```

En la mayoría (si no todos) los lenguajes compilados y fuertemente tipados, tendrías que declarar el tipo de la variable `x`, que tendría que ser un ancestro de los objetos contenidos en la lista. Por tanto, el método `saludar()` sería inaccesible, a menos que uses reflexión, RTTI o alguna manera de buscarlo e invocarlo en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Tu respuesta es impecable. Muchas gracias, me has clarificado mucho la herencia